# How to construct Cayley Table when only few entries are known?

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be a set consisting of 25 elements, that is, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and so on..., and $*$ be a binary operation defined on $A$.

If I know the value of only a few compositions, like for instance $a*b = f$ and $c*d = k$, then how can I construct a composition table for all 25 elements using a `For` loop and such that *Mathematica* compute the rest of the compositions using the known compositions?

Comment: Is your binary operation commutative? Anyway, have a look at `Outer[]`.

Comment: No..

Its not commutative.

Comment: Can you give an example set of compositions (i.e. a presentation of the group)? One that is guaranteed to completely and uniquely define the group?

Comment: Let  
`g[0]**g[2]:>g[1]`,
` g[1]**g[4]:>g[2]` and `g[2]**g[4]:>g[1]` be given (defined) then i want a code which provides`g[0]**g[1]:>g[2]` only

Answer (score 4):

If all you're looking for is to display the Cayley table and do some of those replacements, this is straightforward. We will use `Outer` as suggested by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m). It is the natural way to construct Cayley tables.

As an example, let's take as our group (I'm assuming a group, of course, but I guess you might not be dealing with a group; perhaps a monoid or even some weaker structure; anyway),

```
group = g /@ Range[0, 4];
```

Then, we construct the table as follows:

```
cayleyTable[group_] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, group, group]
```

We are using the built-in function `NonCommutativeMultiply`, which can be written using `Infix` notation with `**`. Finally, we display the table nicely as follows:

```
TableForm[cayleyTable[group], TableHeadings -> {group, group}]
```

[image]

Now, if we have some known compositions, let's combine them into a list of composition rules:

```
compositionRules = {g[0] ** g[0] -> g[0], g[0]**g[1] -> g[1], g[2]**g[4] :> g[1]};
```

Then,

```
TableForm[cayleyTable[group] /. compositionRules, TableHeadings -> {group, group}]
```

[image]

We can also make replacements more general. Recognizing that the only group of order 5 is the cyclic group of order 5, let's make the following rule:

```
cyclicGroupRule = {g[a_] ** g[b_] :> g[Mod[a + b, 5]]};
```

Then,

```
TableForm[cayleyTable[group] /. compositionRules, TableHeadings -> {group, group}]
```

[image]

Comment: `group = g /@ Range[0, 4];`

`cayleyTable[group_] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, group, group];`

`compositionRules = {g[0] ** g[0] -> g[0], g[0] ** g[2] :> g[1], 
   g[2] ** g[4] :> g[1],  g[1] ** g[4] :> g[2]};`

`TableForm[cayleyTable[group] /. compositionRules, 
 TableHeadings -> {group, group}]`

Please check this programe..

Here g[0]**g[1] must be equal to g[2]

but in the output it just show g[0]**g[1] only.

Comment: @TarunGupta. But you haven't included a rule in your compositionRules list that specifies that `g[0]**g[1]` gets replaced with `g[2]`.

Comment: But the composition `g[0]**g[2]:>g[1]`,  `g[1]**g[4]:>g[2]` and `g[2]**g[4]:>g[1]` provides `g[0]**g[1]:>g[2]`.

If a provide all the rules manually then what is the advantage of Mathematica?

Comment: @TarunGupta. Those rules don't work the way you think they do. They are merely [replacement rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), and they *don't compose with each other* in the sense that once the left-hand-side has been replaced with the right-hand side, that's the end. If you would like to "teach" *Mathematica* to "learn" other rules that are *implied* by that set of rules... well, I would ask another question about that, because that seems to be outside the scope of your original question, and we like to keep questions focused.

Comment: @TarunGupta. One of the things that's missing from that set of rules is the idea of an *inverse*. `NonCommutativeMultiply` doesn't have any built-in meaning, and so you have to somehow *tell* *Mathematica* that your set of symbols forms a group, and how to do composition, and what inverses mean, and all of that,